# How can i output this query in json format?

Tags: mysql, json, getjson

and thank's for replys. I have some problem when try to output this query in json format. I want to prevent formatting of json, and the output  will be the same format with table.

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th width=15>Pos.</th>
                        <th width=300 colspan=2>Giocatore / Squadra</th>
                        <th width=40>Totale</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    //Get the data
                    $query_cal = "SELECT idtessera,sum(voto),idsquadra,idtorneo FROM `topgiocatori` where  idtorneo='".$idtorneo."' group by idtessera order by sum(voto) desc,idsquadra asc";
                    $result_cal = mysql_query($query_cal) or die(mysql_error());
                    $posizione=0;
                    while ($riga_cal = mysql_fetch_row($result_cal))
                    {
                    $posizione=$posizione+1;
                    //Get other lines in order by match day
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td width=15><?php printf($posizione); ?></td>
                            <td width=40 align=center><img src="http:#<?php if($riga_cal[0]<>""){printf($riga_cal[0].".jpg");} else { printf("blankx.jpg");}?>" width=40 height=59></a></td>
                            <td width=260><b><?php $giocatore=decodgiocatore($riga_cal[0]); printf($giocatore); ?></b><br><a href="#.php?idsquadra=<?=$riga_cal[2];?>&amp;idtorneo=<?=$idtorneo;?>"><?php $squadra=decodsquadra($riga_cal[2]); printf($squadra); ?></td>
                            <td width=40 align="center"><?php printf($riga_cal[1]); ?></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                printf("</table><br>");
                ?>
```